# CONDITIONAL SUM T-SQL

Tags: sql, null, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a table in this format

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
A    NULL  4
A    NULL  4
A    VAL1  4
A    VAL2  4
A    VAL3  4
B    NULL  5
B    VAL1  6
```

I need to bring out the output as follows:

```
COL1 TOTAL VALID
A    20     12
B    11     6
```

My Question is, how do I get the 'VALID' column - it should do sum of col3 only if col2 is not null.

I was able to get the 'TOTAL' field correctly using SUM and group by clauses. But how do I compute the 'VALID' column?

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT col1
     , SUM(col3) AS TOTAL
     , SUM(CASE WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL THEN col3 ELSE NULL END) AS VALID
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY col1
```

The "trick" is to use the CASE expression to conditionally return the value of col3.

Comment: There are multiple ways to return the specified resultset. One big advantage of this approach is performance; this uses only one pass through the data. This avoids the overhead of a correlated subquery (which gets run for every row returned by the outer query) (see the answer from SLaks). It also avoids the overhead of derived tables (i.e. materializing inline views) and a join operation (as in the answer from Chris Shain, which btw doesn't guarantee a correct result.)

Comment: That's really elegant and like you say, only one pass is needed

Answer (score -2):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(Col3) AS Total, 
       (SELECT SUM(Filtered.Col3) 
        FROM table Filtered 
        WHERE Filtered.Col1 = Grouped.Col1 
          AND Filtered.Col2 IS NOT NULL
       ) AS Valid
FROM table Grouped
GROUP BY Col1
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work...

```
SELECT B.COL1, SUM(A.COL3) AS TOTAL, SUM(B.COL3) AS VALID
FROM 
(SELECT COL1, COL3 FROM ORIGINAL WHERE COL2 IS NULL) A
INNER JOIN (SELECT COL1, COL3 FROM ORIGINAL) B ON A.COL1 = B.COL1
```